# Clone iOS 7 Tab Bar in HTML

Tags: html, css

I would like to recreate the navigation bar from iOS 7, with HTML, CSS and JS.

So far I have used a fixed bootstrap navbar, with Font Awesome glyphs for icons. I'd like assistance in tweaking the active status of the various elements and stacking a glyph above a line of text.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I added a Bootstrap navbar to the top of the screen, and used fontawesome for the various icons. I then used CSS to make it white, with dark grey icons. I'm having trouble with the dividers between different icons, and moving the navbar to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I have updated it again @DanielA.White

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a bootstrap theme to do this.

http://jasonbradley.me/bootstrap-ios7-theme/